# On start up to automatically open the project which was open before closing the ide

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2005

In visual studio 2013 how to set to automatically open the project (on startup) which was lastly opened before closing the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Options - Environment - Startup - Load last loaded solution.